# How do you write to an xml file in win32 C++?

Tags: c++, xml, winapi

I would like to write a simple xml file using `xmllite` in `win32 c++`.  the file will be saved over every time the user saves.  How do I do this?  I'd rather not include any new libraries for this...

Answer (score 6):

Start by reading the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx#S4

Answer (score 3):

Since your question specifies C++, and you've not specified why you must use xmllite, I will suggest another package for your consideration called [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/).

It's a pretty simple tool, and uses straight C++.